# Implementing GB-RBMs for real-valued data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gaussian, rbm, dbn

I am trying to implement a Deep Belief Network for speech recognition. And hence, need the first layer of RBM to have gaussian visible units.

I used @Andrej Karpathy's matrbm (https://code.google.com/p/matrbm/) and made some changes to convert the Bernouli-Bernouli RBMs to a Gaussian-Bernouli one.

The changed version is available at http://pastebin.com/KTPHnizd

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Comment: @Pedrom I am not sure whether the way I am calculating the hidden layer states and visible states (line 109-127) are consistent and correct.

Comment: This is more of a request for code review than a problem that someone here can help you solve.